# Difference in mean equals 50 but p-value is 0.05

Tags: distributions, p-value

I recently read a paper about changes in joint movement before and after therapy. They report a difference in joint movement from mean =50° to mean 0° after treatment, but a p-value of 0.05. Sample size n= 29. Maximum possible movement in that joint is 110 degrees (-20° up to  90°).
In my opinion beside the difference in mean (50°) there must be many examples with less difference, otherwise the p-Value would be smaller. Any ways to conclude from the given values to the possible distribution ? The samples must have a skewed distribution, otherwise the great p-value cannot be explained. Am I right? Any ways to simulate this with R? When I use standard- normal distributed values I always end up with p-Values beneath 0.0000...
Thanks Peter

Comment: What hypothesis test did they use?

Comment: Any idea of the standard deviations in the control and treatment groups?  The difference in means is large but of the variance is also large,  that would explain the p-value.

Comment: If they have given a confidence interval that would also help. Editors of health journals started asking for them about three decades ago but perhaps the message is yet to get through.

Comment: what is great p-value ?  you need a little more reading of literature on p-values. It does not reflect what you have in mind ? I think we have a calculated p value and a simulated p-value.

Comment: Thanks for all comments.
In the paper there is no standard deviation and no CI. Very strange. Only mean and p-value. Because they only have 16 observations, I tried many combinations of values with given mean and range and calculated the  respective p-values. Never ! could get a p-value greater than 0.00001. Very strange data. I am a little bit concerned about the fact, that they publish such data.